# Get-PrinterDrvier cmdlet complains about unreachable RPC server

Tags: powershell, remote-access, rpc

I am trying to receive a list of installed printer drivers from several Windows 7 and Windows 10 machines.

```
Get-PrinterDriver -ComputerName Win7Machine
```

This works on **some** of our Win7 machines and on others it doesn't.

[image]

HRESULT 0x800706ba translates to: The RPC Server is not reachable.

Okay fine, so I suspected that there is something wrong with our modified RPC configuration. But `Get-Process` on the same machine returns with results.

```
Get-Process -ComputerName Win7Machine
```

So any idea on what could be wrong here?

Comment: Ensure your WMI is enabled (and accessible) on the boxes.  It uses RPC and is probably the underlying process.

Comment: `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PrinterDriver -Computer Win7Machine` works... so that should be fine...

Comment: According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875824.aspx) the Spooler service uses ports 139 and 445. Did you check that the Spooler service is actually running and these 2 ports are opened in the firewall?

Comment: Did you confirm the spooler is running?  `Get-Service -Name Spooler`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Yes, I have ensured that the Spooler Service is running.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers 445/TCP is on both systems open and reachable (both systems means, that one that works and that one that doesn't). If I use `PortQry.exe -n Win7Machine -e 135` it resolves the Services correctly`